# Does setMinimumIdle() respects the setIdleTimeout () in HikariCP Datasource

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am trying to create a connection pool by using HikariCP for Postgres. The pool should always have one active session/connection and the remaining connections should be on-demand which Hikari will take care of. To do the same, configured Datasource like below

```
private static HikariDataSource dataSource = null;
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/dbname");
config.setUsername("USERNAME");
config.setPassword("PASSWORD");
config.setMinimumIdle(1);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(5);     
config.setIdleTimeout(10000);
dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

MinimumIdle(1) always keeps the one active session/open connection to DB unless the program or server closed and the remaining 4 connections will be created on-demand if they do not exist already in the pool.

IdleTimeout(10000) removes any connection object which is idle in the pool for more than 10 seconds and observed that it won't apply to any of the connections set to MinimumIdle(Here it is 1).

Is my understanding correct and serves my requirement? Appreciate your suggestions here.

Comment: Minimum Idle isn't equal to Minimum active

Comment: Okay. What could be the idle implementation here?